# How can I have a site with arrow buttons to open different sections within my homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Me and my friend at work are looking to create a site for his cookery business. He has put together some designs on paper that he would like for his site. One of the ideas is to have his homepage that will have 4 different sections on top of each other but they will have an arrow button that will allow that section to open and close. (attached image for visual)

I have designed sites previously where you have text links, when clicked on they take you to that section on the same page but not sure how i have a drop down feature as such, as within the drop down he will have text in there so similar to a read more button.

If somebody could please advise on how i could get something like this created as I have tried searching on Google but not come across anything like this, any examples or help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

[design idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PvBD.jpg)

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Apologies Paulie_D, was really looking to just find out what the feature was called if there was any, not looking for a debate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is collapse-able ui for the front end. Technically it is used for various elements like menus and tabs.

In general term it is called accordion, there are various ready made that you can use.

This one is a simple html and jquery tutorial : [Click Here](http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-an-accordion-with-html-css-jquery)

- http://www.snyderplace.com/demos/accordion.html
- https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

If you are using bootstrap then Bootstrap has similar feature as well.

Comment: Thanks Gandalf the White, that will get me going.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for what is called "accordion" or "Collapsible" there are a lot of examples you are able to find. Best and easy way will be using bootstrap, here is an [example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp)

Comment: Think you can easily add arrows or  any other icon you might want, but I think this a pretty good example: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/accordion-menu

Comment: there are a lot of good examples among the web, i.e. 
http://bootsnipp.com/tags/accordion